# How to put asterisk over a letter

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

[image]

How can I write an asterisk symbol over a letter? Thank you very much

Comment: @JouleV: No, it is not \overset{}{}. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JouleV: I am sorry. It is not. I am looking similar to \overline{\mathbf M}

Comment: Then I literally can't figure out what you are looking for. `\overline` has nothing to do here, because it draws a line over a (set of) symbol, not add a symbol above another symbol. Please explain things more.

Comment: @JouleV: Sorry to confuse you with the \overline. I am looking for a symbol (asterisk) over a Letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version for `\mathbf` I call `\overstarbf`, which does not account for italic slant and sets the argument in `\mathbf`.  The other macro `\overstar`, accounts for the slant (here taken as `.2`) of the italic-set argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\overstarbf[1]{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\SavedStyle\mathbf{#1}}{\smash{\SavedStyle*}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}}
\newcommand\overstar[1]{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\copy0}{\kern.2\ht0\smash{\SavedStyle*}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}}
\begin{document}
\Shortstack[l]{
$\overstarbf{M}^{\mathrm{f}}$
$\scriptstyle\overstarbf{M}^{\mathrm{f}}$
$\scriptscriptstyle\overstarbf{M}^{\mathrm{f}}$}
vs.\@
\Shortstack[r]{
$\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm{f}}$
$\scriptstyle\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm{f}}$
$\scriptscriptstyle\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm{f}}$}
\quad
\Shortstack[l]{
$\overstar{M}^2\overstar{x}$
$\scriptstyle\overstar{M}^2\overstar{x}$
$\scriptscriptstyle\overstar{M}^2\overstar{x}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT** (script style star overset)

I realize I need to modify my `scalerel` package to make not only the current math style accessible (which I do via `\SavedStyle`), but that it would be useful to make the script form relative to the current style accessible, as well.

I do it here as `\SavedSubStyle`, between the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, which also requires small additions to the definition of `\ThisStyle`.  I will eventually get around to incorporating this into the package directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\makeatletter
\def\SavedSubStyle{\csname @mstyle\s@switch\endcsname}
\renewcommand\ThisStyle[1]{%
\ifmmode%
\def\@mmode{T}\mathchoice%
{\edef\m@switch{D}\edef\s@switch{S}\LMex=1ex\relax\LMpt=1pt\relax#1}%
{\edef\m@switch{T}\edef\s@switch{S}\LMex=1ex\relax\LMpt=1pt\relax#1}%
{\edef\m@switch{S}\edef\s@switch{s}\LMex=\scriptstyleScaleFactor ex\relax%
\LMpt=\scriptstyleScaleFactor pt\relax#1}%
{\edef\m@switch{s}\edef\s@switch{s}\LMex=\scriptscriptstyleScaleFactor ex\relax%
\LMpt=\scriptscriptstyleScaleFactor pt\relax#1}%
\else%
\def\@mmode{F}%
\edef\m@switch{T}\edef\s@switch{S}\LMex=1ex\relax\LMpt=1pt\relax#1%
\fi%
}
%
\makeatother
\newcommand\overstarbf[1]{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\SavedStyle\mathbf{#1}}{\smash{\SavedSubStyle*}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}}
\newcommand\overstar[1]{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\copy0}{\kern.2\ht0\smash{\SavedSubStyle*}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}}
\begin{document}
\Shortstack[l]{
$\overstarbf{M}^{\mathrm{f}}$
$\scriptstyle\overstarbf{M}^{\mathrm{f}}$
$\scriptscriptstyle\overstarbf{M}^{\mathrm{f}}$}
vs.\@
\Shortstack[r]{
$\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm{f}}$
$\scriptstyle\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm{f}}$
$\scriptscriptstyle\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm{f}}$}
\quad
\Shortstack[l]{
$\overstar{M}^2\overstar{x}$
$\scriptstyle\overstar{M}^2\overstar{x}$
$\scriptscriptstyle\overstar{M}^2\overstar{x}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, Thank you very much @Steven

Comment: @Prakash I have revised my answer a bit, to allow for two versions: one for `bf` arguments, the other not.

Comment: @Prakash I have also added a **SUPPLEMENT** if you prefer the asterisk to be in a smaller script style than the current size.

Comment: Note: this answer is subject of a new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685850/how-to-avoid-lines-overlapping-when-using-scalerel-with-stackrel.

Answer (score 6):

It is very simple with the `accents` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{accents} 

\begin{document}

\[ \accentset{\ast}{\mathbf{M}}^{\mathbf{f}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a simpler answer