# How to avoid lines overlapping when using scalerel with stackrel

Tags: scalerel

I would like to avoid lines overlapping when using an overset asterisk according to the solution for scalerel posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484467/297096)

My document cannot see that it makes the symbols have a larger height, and so the lines are not spaced sufficiently far appart, also in equations.

I realize that a comment would be appropriate, but my reputation is not sufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\overstarbf[1]{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\SavedStyle\mathbf{#1}}{\smash{\SavedStyle*}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}}
\newcommand\overstar[1]{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\copy0}{\kern.2\ht0\smash{\SavedStyle*}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}}
\begin{document}
$\frac{A}{\overstar{M}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you add a small complete document to your question here that shows the issue. While that code would be partly copied from the other question it still helps to make this question more stand-alone and easier to reproduce. Also I have added a comment to the original answer to notify the answerer that you have posted this follow-up question.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `\smash{}` from the definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\overstarbf[1]{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\SavedStyle\mathbf{#1}}{\smash{\SavedStyle*}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}}
\newcommand\overstar[1]{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\copy0}{\kern.2\ht0\smash{\SavedStyle*}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}}
\newcommand\overstarnosmash[1]{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\copy0}{\kern.2\ht0\SavedStyle*}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}}
\begin{document}
$\frac{A}{\overstar{M}}$

$\frac{A}{\overstarnosmash{M}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this seems to work!